# Moments and forces in static equilibrium: bonus question

Tags: geometry

It's my first time here on Stack Exchange! Recieved a tricky bonus question in class today and was wondering if someone might take a look - I'd be incredibly grateful! Solving for Cy, Cx and Mc.
[image]

Comment: Look more like a physics question? (Hi this is Math SE here, wellcome~)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Your question will probably be more well-received if you include some information on what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks, I've just been browsing the stack exchange for the last few minutes, coming to terms with it's size aha. Thus far, I've equated all moments and all forces to zero about an arbitrary point I placed at C, and attempted to solve for Cx and Cy. I'm not particularly certain about Mc and I haven't recieved the correct answers for Cx and Cy as yet.

Answer (score 0):

It is more a physics question than a math one, but here is a go:

$\sum F_x=0$, hence $C_x+T_{BD}\times \cos \alpha-Q=0$, with $\cos \alpha=\dfrac{600}{\sqrt{250^2+600^2}}$

That is $C_x=Q-T_{BD}\times \dfrac{600}{\sqrt{250^2+600^2}}$

With the same along the $y$ axis you get $C_y=P+T_{BD}\times \dfrac{250}{\sqrt{250^2+600^2}}$

For the momentum $\sum M=0$ you have $M_c=-(P\times 0.5+Q\times 0.4)$